# Python Executable file

Tags: python, executable

I am trying to run tutorial for creating executable file available in below site

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

But when I tried to run below setup.py file as instructed in tutorial I am getting error "ImportError: No module named 'py2exe'"

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

Can anyone help me to know what is the issue here

Comment: Have you installed the py2exe module?

Comment: I am trying to install from 
 "https://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/" but when i tried to execute "py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.5.exe" it throws error "The program can't start because MSVCR71.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"  I am not sure exactly about this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are a few simple steps needed to use py2exe **once you've installed it**:

The tutorial assumes you've already installed py2exe.
You can do this using pip.

```
pip install py2exe
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help able to resolve issue

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) to install pip on your windows machine, if you haven't already installed it.
Then use `pip install py2exe` to install your module.